# Manage/import Terraform resource indirectly created by Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

We are using Terraform's `aws_db_instance` to create an RDS PostgreSQL instance. When we set `enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports`, this creates a CloudWatch Log Group for RDS logs.

Next, we'd like to set the retention period for this Log Group to 7 days, rather than its default "Never expire" setting. However, we're unable to do this using `aws_cloudwatch_log_group`, since the Log Group already exists but is not directly managed by Terraform.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
# foo.tf

resource "aws_db_instance" "foo" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  db_name              = "mydb"
  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "12"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "bar" {
  name = "/aws/rds/instance/${aws_db_instance.foo.id}/postgresql"
  retention_in_days = 7
}
```

This leads to the error below:

> Error: Creating CloudWatch Log Group failed: ResourceAlreadyExistsException: The specified log group already exists:  The CloudWatch Log Group '/aws/rds/instance/terraform-/postgresql' already exists.

**How can we tell terraform within this module (`foo.tf`) to manage the Log Group that is *implicitly* created by `aws_db_instance`?**

**Caveats**: I cannot use `terraform import` here. This must stay contained within Terraform modules.

Comment: Does this happen when you create new or only when you later add the log group resource? I would expect this to work as is because the log group typically isn't automatically created until the first delivery of a log.

Comment: @Paolo you can't set the retention period if you are using a datasource.

Comment: @MarkB Oh, I missed that. Well he certainly can't do that by using a separate `resource` then, he'll have to use a script or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want now that the resources already exist in AWS. The only option now is to use `terraform import`.

If you are trying to make this module reusable, and want to prevent this issue from happening again in the future, then you should add a [depends_on](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) to the `aws_db_instance` resource, so that it waits for the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` resource to exist, before creating the database resource. If the log group already exists, then AWS will just use it instead of trying to create it for you automatically.

Comment: *If the log group already exists, then AWS will just use it instead of trying to create it for you automatically.* uhm, are you sure it won't just error out complaining it already exists?

Comment: @Paolo yes, I've done this exact thing before, with RDS, Lambda and other service that will automatically create log groups for you. If you create them first, then the AWS resource will use it and not complain.

Comment: Makes sense. Note to readers, using this method you'll need to generate a name for the RDS resource (e.g. using `random`) so that both `resource`s can reference it.